# How to get a single character from an NSString

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsstring

This is what I'm using

```
[[remaining_string substringFromIndex:k] substringToIndex:1]
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Did any answer help you? Just click the check mark to mark it as an accepted solution or vote it up. And please check your other questions for possible solutions, too. Thanks! :)   (And yes, this is copy-pasted so new users are aware of the voting system.)

Comment: Your answer doesn't help. It doesn't even work.

Comment: But it's exactly the same as yours except it's one method call instead of two. o_O

Comment: If you try to run it it doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [`characterAtIndex`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/characterAtIndex%3a)

```
NSString *myString = @"Hello, World";
unichar myChar = [myString characterAtIndex:k];
```

Note that this returns a `unichar`. You can use [`substringWithRange`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/substringWithRange%3a) (see Henrik's answer) if you want a `NSString`.

Comment: What if you wanted to return an NSString?

Answer (score 2):

And if you want a NSString this should work:

```
string2 = [string1 substringWithRange: NSMakeRange (k, 1)];
```